# android webview not loading/opening pdf

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

My webview is loading google chrome. When the user browses the webview app he can navigate to any links which is working fine. But when the user navigates to a link which contains pdf my webview fails to open or  download the file. How can I achieve it?

```
public class WebViewPage extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
Button closeweb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_page);

    webView =findViewById(R.id.webview);
    closeweb = findViewById(R.id.closeweb);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.in");
     closeweb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(WebViewPage.this, HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or perhaps if you want to open the PDF or any other format like XLSX or etc... you can use this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    if (url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".xlsx") || url.endsWith(".xls") || url.endsWith(".doc") || url.endsWith(".docx") || url.endsWith(".ppt") || url.endsWith(".pptx")) {
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
       
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will use the services of google for opening any type of files(supported by google docs).

Comment: - Its not loading web page..  net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Comment: changing http to https is working but its not loading google chrome  as landing page.. I have shared the screenshot

Comment: @Abm i have edited the answer. Please check it now

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me and I am able to achieve opening of pdf

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    webView.loadUrl(url);
    if (url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".xlsx") || url.endsWith(".xls") || url.endsWith(".doc") || url.endsWith(".docx") || url.endsWith(".ppt") || url.endsWith(".pptx")) {
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
       
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But, this will NOT open it in the webView itself. It will open another PDF opener app for that!

Comment: @ Sambhav Khandelwal - yes..