# WebView is Loading Blank in .NET MAUI Android App

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, maui, .net-8.0

WebView is loading as blank page in Android app targeting MAUI .NET8. But, same code loads WebView content in Windows platform and also in browser as well. It is not working only in Android platform.

The source URL we are setting is a **http web URL (.aspx file)** which in-turn redirect to another URL which will show PDF file.

We have tried out all the options suggested that we found over the internet regarding this but nothing didn`t work.

```
<WebView x:Name="webView"/>

webView.Source = "http://.aspx URL";
```

Answer (score 1):

I create a new project to test the **http web URL (.aspx file)** and it can't be loaded unless I changed the `http` to `https`. And you can also add the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` into the `<application>` tag of the **\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest** such as:

```
<application ....  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
```

> The source URL we are setting is a http web URL (.aspx file) which in-turn redirect to another URL which will show PDF file.

**The android webview does not support to disaplay the pdf file**. You can use the [google service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74084722/17455524) to do that.

Here is my code in the xaml:

```
<WebView HeightRequest="800"
         Source="http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx"
         x:Name="webview"/>
```

And the code behind:

```
//delcare the class for the android platform
#if ANDROID
        public class Myclient : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
        {
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                if (request.Url.ToString().EndsWith(".pdf"))
                {
                    view.LoadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + request.Url.ToString());
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
#endif

//use the class in the page's OnHandlerChanged method
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
     base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
     var androidwebview = (webview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView);
     androidwebview.SetWebViewClient(new Myclient());
     androidwebview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you lack some setting for Android Webview

```
with(webView.settings) {
            useWideViewPort = true
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        }
```

Comment: note: the question is about MAUI, so C#

Comment: Oh, sorry for my mistake